# Filling array of functions with loop in C

Tags: c, arrays

The following code is just a contrived example which I invented to test what is in principle possible in C. The function `test` returns a pointer to an array of ten pointers to functions returning integers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f0(){return 0;}
int f1(){return 1;} 
int f2(){return 2;}
int f3(){return 3;}
int f4(){return 4;}
int f5(){return 5;}
int f6(){return 6;}
int f7(){return 7;}
int f8(){return 8;}
int f9(){return 9;}

int (*((*test())[10]))(){
  int (*(*ret)[10])() = malloc(sizeof(int(*[10])()));
  (*ret)[0] = f0;
  (*ret)[1] = f1;
  (*ret)[2] = f2;
  (*ret)[3] = f3;
  (*ret)[4] = f4;
  (*ret)[5] = f5;
  (*ret)[6] = f6;
  (*ret)[7] = f7;
  (*ret)[8] = f8;
  (*ret)[9] = f9;
  return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i;
  int (*(*farray)[10])() = test();
  for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    printf("%d\n", ((*farray)[i])());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Now I wonder if we stipulate that we cannot change the `main`-method, is there any way to make this code shorter?

The program must output the numbers 0 to 10.

Can the array `*ret` filled by a for-loop? It doesn't have to be safe or clean, it must just conform to either C89, C99 or C11.

Comment: I think ## macro will be useful here.

Comment: Basically you're asking if there is a way to deduce the memory address of the functions f0, f1, etc, such that an identity like f1 = f0 + "lengthof(f0)" holds.  AFAIK, there is no way to do this, so you are left with several cute alternatives: 1. write f0, f1, etc. in a giant assembly language function, so that such a identity holds (but this won't make the whole program shorter), or (2) change the condition that the function pointer can take a parameter.  Some compilers let you initialize ret with something like ret = { f0, f1, ...) but not all.

Comment: It looks like he asking to shorten the code using loop instead of assigning each element with the function name in the function test().

Comment: `int (*((*test())[10]))(){` O.o

Comment: Why does this need to be a dynamically-allocated array?  Also, some well-placed `typedef`s would make it a lot more readable.

Comment: You should `free(farray)`. Also, `malloc( sizeof *ret );` would increase readability

Answer (score 2):

Declaring a local array and then copying it would be my preference.  Not to mention some typedefs to reduce eye-strain:

```
typedef int (*func_type)();
typedef func_type func_array_type[10];

func_array_type * test()
{
   func_array_type fns = { f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9 };
   func_array_type *ret = malloc( sizeof(func_array_type) );
   if( ret ) memcpy( ret, fns, sizeof(func_array_type) );
   return ret;
}
```

Since the returned functions in this case would always be the same, that local array could be declared static.  Then you'd have to ask yourself whether you need dynamic allocation at all:

```
func_array_type * test()
{
   static func_array_type fns = { f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9 };
   return &fns;
}
```

Probably depends on whether the caller will promise not to modify the array.